# Import another table into a column in MySQL database. Getting error `TABLE IS FULL`

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm trying to import a 24 GB table into another table column but i get the error `TABLE IS FULL` every time i try to import the data. `INNODB` is the `storage engine` used and i have already set `innodb_file_per_table` scheme to `autoextend`.

I have set `innodb_data_file_path` to `ibdata1:12M:autoextended` and have also set the `table_size` to `512Mb` and `max_heap_table_size` to `512Mb`. I'm using MySQL version `5.7.23(64 bit)`. The database im trying to import contains images in `long blob` format. Please do let me know if more information is required. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that you didn't simply run out of hard drive space (during execution, to include potential temporary tables)?

Comment: I have 50 Gb storage out of which im using only 1.729 Gb (before execution).Although I haven't checked the storage during execution but the database i want to import is 24 Gb in size.

Comment: How are you importing that data? It sounded like you wanted to copy from an existing table to another table, which can very well generate a temporary table about the same size as the final table (e.g. 2*24GB), so please check during runtime, although this is less likely if you load the data row by row (using php/load data infile/...). In general, the most likely reason for this error is lack of hdd space, so try to exclude it first; also check if you filesystem supports files that big, e.g. 4GB would be a typical size limit for FAT32; also maybe your hoster set some limits.

Comment: You need to show the query that's getting the error. It's hard to understand what you mean by "import a table into a column".

Answer (score 1):

Your question reads as if you are shoving 24GB into a single column of a single row.  That is not possible.

`LONGBLOB` is limited to 4GB.  Furthermore, it is difficult to load anywhere near that much into a single cell due to other buffers, etc.

If you are spreading that 24GB across multiple rows in a single column or some other arrangement, please edit your Question to clarify.

Note about images:  When storing an image associated with a row, and that image will be delivered to an HTML page, it is usually more convenient to put the image in a file, then construct `<img src=...>` to point to the file.

Comment: Yes i wanted to create a column of `LONGBLOB` type as i was trying to save images in that column. Thank you informing me on limited size of `LONGBLOB`.

Comment: @prashantbana - I added a note on a way to handle images without threatening the `BLOB` issues discussed.